Set Mongoose query function by a conditional constant in Typescript
I have a function that should check if an entry in db exists based on an input ID.
If yes, update the entry, else create a new entry.
I am assigning either updateOne or create to a const, and then calling it later on.
But when I run this it gets me this error:
"MongooseError: Model.create() cannot run without a model as this."
export async function dbUpdateWishlist(wl: wishlistDBType): Promise<BoolTuple> {
    const queryFn =
        (await WishlistModel.exists({
            discordIdentifier: wl.discordIdentifier,
        })) !== null
            ? WishlistModel.updateOne
            : WishlistModel.create;

    const response = await queryFn(wl)
        .then(() => {
            return [true, 'DB save successful'];
        })
        .catch((err: Error) => {
            console.log('DB save failed ', err);
            return [false, 'DB save failed'];
        });

    return response as BoolTuple;
}

I can (and have successfully) run the conditional in an If statement and then duplicate the response code in both if and else block. I am trying to avoid repeating code.
Working option:
export async function dbUpdateWishlist(wl: wishlistDBType): Promise<BoolTuple> {
    let response;
    if (
        (await WishlistModel.exists({
            discordIdentifier: wl.discordIdentifier,
        })) !== null
    ) {
        // If exists then update.
        response = await WishlistModel.updateOne(wl)
            .then(() => {
                return [true, 'DB save successful'];
            })
            .catch((err: Error) => {
                console.log('DB save failed ', err);
                return [false, 'DB save failed'];
            });
    } else {
        // Otherwise create a new entry.
        response = await WishlistModel.create(wl)
            .then(() => {
                return [true, 'DB save successful'];
            })
            .catch((err: Error) => {
                console.log('DB save failed ', err);
                return [false, 'DB save failed'];
            });
    }

    return response as BoolTuple;
}

(I am aware the return tuples are not doing much for this function, but they are conforming to the rest of the application.)
New version from comments that works:
export async function dbUpdateWishlist(wl: wishlistDBType): Promise<BoolTuple> {
    const queryFn =
        (await WishlistModel.exists({
            discordIdentifier: wl.discordIdentifier,
        })) !== null
            ? WishlistModel.updateOne.bind(WishlistModel)
            : WishlistModel.create.bind(WishlistModel);

    try {
        await queryFn(wl);
        return [true, 'DB save successful'];
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('DB save failed ', err);
        return [false, 'DB save failed'];
    }
}


99% of the time mixing async/await with .then and .catch is a sure sign that you're making a mistake or don't understand these features

WishlistModel.create needs to be WishlistModel.create.bind(WishlistModel)

It's await queryFn.call(WishlistModel, wl)

Btw I would recommend to use .then(…, …) instead of .then(…).catch(…) for creating your BoolTuple

@AluanHaddad Alright, if I understand correctly I should do error handling in try-catch blocks instead when using async-await such as in the new version in my latest edit?

@justaprogrammer2 indeed that's what I was suggesting. The key point though is being consistent and keeping it simple. Typically, using the reason you would use promise combinators directly in an async context only if you want to handle some promises out of band (not waiting for them as soon as you create them) for example if you want to fire off operations in parallel (e.g. await Promise.all(endpoints.map(fetch).then(r => r.json())); or are maintaining some kind of external state like a promise queue (i.e. if you're writing your own loader).
